# Create a pivot table in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new to VBA.
I have issues in this part of the code when it comes to adding the pivot table to a new sheet, the indicated line is where excel shows the error:

> run time error ´5´ "invalid procedure call or argument"

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'
    ' problem with the next line
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Pivot").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( \_
        "PivotTable12").PivotFields("Claimable Amount"), "Sum of Claimable Amount", \_
        xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos").Subtotals = \_
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos").LayoutForm = \_
        xlTabular
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID").Subtotals = \_
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID").LayoutForm \_
        = xlTabular
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID"). \_
        RepeatLabels = True
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End Sub
```

To be able to run succesfully the code to create the pivot table with the rows and configuration that i need in a new sheet

Comment: You can try recording a macro while you are doing this manually. Recorded script may show you some hints.

Comment: This is from a recorded macro, and i really have no clue

Comment: the error occurs on `Application.CutCopyMode = False`? That line clears the clipboard. Try commenting out that line and see if your actual PivotTable code runs